bitbucket aws codepipeline build notification
import { CfnOutput, Duration, RemovalPolicy } from 'aws-cdk-lib'
import * as codebuild from 'aws-cdk-lib/aws-codebuild'
import * as codepipeline from 'aws-cdk-lib/aws-codepipeline'
import * as codepipeline_actions from 'aws-cdk-lib/aws-codepipeline-actions'
import * as events from 'aws-cdk-lib/aws-events'
import * as targets from 'aws-cdk-lib/aws-events-targets'
import * as iam from 'aws-cdk-lib/aws-iam'
import * as lambda from 'aws-cdk-lib/aws-lambda'
import * as s3 from 'aws-cdk-lib/aws-s3'
import { Construct } from 'constructs'
import { StackContext, use } from 'sst/constructs'
import { BITBUCKET_BRANCH, BITBUCKET_OWNER, BITBUCKET_REPO } from './config'
import { Connections } from './connections'

export interface BasePipelineProps {
  app: StackContext['app']
  stack: StackContext['stack']
  baseName: string
  pullRequests?: boolean
  branch?: string
  triggerOnPush?: boolean
}

export class BasePipeline extends Construct {
  pipeline: codepipeline.Pipeline
  buildRole: iam.Role
  sourceOutput: codepipeline.Artifact
  sourceAction: codepipeline_actions.CodeStarConnectionsSourceAction
  pipelineRole: iam.Role
  constructor(scope: Construct, id: string, props: BasePipelineProps) {
    super(scope, id)
    const { app, stack, triggerOnPush = true } = props
    const baseName = app.logicalPrefixedName(props.baseName)
    this.sourceOutput = new codepipeline.Artifact(`${baseName}SourceOutput`)
    const branch = props.branch ?? BITBUCKET_BRANCH

    this.buildRole = new iam.Role(stack, `${baseName}CodeBuildRole`, {
      assumedBy: new iam.ServicePrincipal('codebuild.amazonaws.com'),
    })

    const { connectionArn, connectionPolicy } = use(Connections)

    this.buildRole.addToPolicy(
      new iam.PolicyStatement({
        effect: iam.Effect.ALLOW,
        actions: [
          'logs:CreateLogGroup',
          'logs:CreateLogStream',
          'logs:PutLogEvents',
          's3:GetBucketAcl',
          's3:GetBucketLocation',
          's3:GetObject',
          's3:GetObjectVersion',
          's3:PutObject',
          'sts:AssumeRole',
        ],
        resources: ['*'],
      }),
    )

    // Grant permissions to the build role
    this.buildRole.addManagedPolicy(iam.ManagedPolicy.fromAwsManagedPolicyName('AdministratorAccess'))

    // Create Pipeline role
    this.pipelineRole = new iam.Role(stack, `${baseName}CodePipelineRole`, {
      assumedBy: new iam.ServicePrincipal('codepipeline.amazonaws.com'),
    })

    this.pipelineRole.addToPolicy(
      new iam.PolicyStatement({
        effect: iam.Effect.ALLOW,
        actions: [
          'logs:CreateLogGroup',
          'logs:CreateLogStream',
          'logs:PutLogEvents',
          's3:GetObject',
          's3:GetObjectVersion',
          's3:GetBucketVersioning',
          's3:PutObject',
          'codebuild:BatchGetBuilds',
          'codebuild:StartBuild',
          'codebuild:StopBuild',
          'codestar-connections:UseConnection',
          'codestar-connections:GetConnection',
          'codestar-connections:PassConnection',
        ],
        resources: ['*'],
      }),
    )

    this.pipelineRole.addManagedPolicy(connectionPolicy)

    this.sourceAction = new codepipeline_actions.CodeStarConnectionsSourceAction({
      actionName: 'Source',
      owner: BITBUCKET_OWNER,
      repo: BITBUCKET_REPO,
      branch: branch,
      output: this.sourceOutput,
      connectionArn: connectionArn,
      triggerOnPush,
      variablesNamespace: 'pipeVariables',
      codeBuildCloneOutput: true,
      role: this.pipelineRole,
    })

    // create the artifact bucket
    const artifactBucket = new s3.Bucket(stack, `${baseName}ArtifactBucket`, {
      versioned: true,
      removalPolicy: RemovalPolicy.DESTROY,
      autoDeleteObjects: true,
    })

    // Create Pipeline
    this.pipeline = new codepipeline.Pipeline(stack, `${baseName}Pipeline`, {
      pipelineType: codepipeline.PipelineType.V2,
      pipelineName: `${baseName}-pipeline`,
      crossAccountKeys: true,
      restartExecutionOnUpdate: true,
      executionMode: codepipeline.ExecutionMode.PARALLEL,
      role: this.pipelineRole,
      artifactBucket,
      ...(props.pullRequests && {
        triggers: [
          {
            providerType: codepipeline.ProviderType.CODE_STAR_SOURCE_CONNECTION,
            gitConfiguration: {
              sourceAction: this.sourceAction,
              pullRequestFilter: [
                {
                  events: [codepipeline.GitPullRequestEvent.OPEN, codepipeline.GitPullRequestEvent.UPDATED],
                  branchesIncludes: [branch],
                },
              ],
            },
          },
        ],
      }),
    })

    // Create Lint Project
    const lintProject = new codebuild.PipelineProject(stack, `${baseName}LintProject`, {
      buildSpec: codebuild.BuildSpec.fromObject({
        version: '0.2',
        phases: {
          install: {
            'runtime-versions': {
              nodejs: '20',
            },
            commands: ['npm install -g pnpm', 'pnpm install --store-dir=/root/.pnpm-store'],
          },
          build: {
            commands: ['pnpm lint'],
          },
        },
        cache: {
          paths: ['node_modules/**/*', '**/node_modules/**/*', 'web/.next/cache/**/*', '/root/.pnpm-store/**/*'],
        },
      }),
      environment: {
        buildImage: codebuild.LinuxBuildImage.STANDARD_7_0,
        privileged: true,
        environmentVariables: {
          DOCKER: { value: 'true' },
          NODE_OPTIONS: { value: '--max_old_space_size=8192' },
        },
      },
      role: this.buildRole,
    })

    this.pipeline.addStage({
      stageName: 'Source',
      actions: [this.sourceAction],
    })

    this.pipeline.addStage({
      stageName: 'Lint',
      actions: [
        new codepipeline_actions.CodeBuildAction({
          actionName: 'Lint',
          project: lintProject,
          input: this.sourceOutput,
          role: this.pipelineRole,
        }),
      ],
    })

    new CfnOutput(stack, `${baseName}PipelineURL`, {
      value: `https://${stack.region}.console.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/home?region=${stack.region}#/view/${this.pipeline.pipelineName}`,
      description: 'Pipeline URL',
    })
  }
}

Given this pipeline, I'm trying to have the branch/build status showing on bitbucket but I have no luck. What else am I missing?

I don't see anything related to the build badge in your code - what have you tried? Here's the documentation on codebuild build badges: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/sample-build-badges.html

@gshpychka if i put badge:true on pipelineProjects, i get an error while trying to deploy: Badge is not supported for source type CODEPIPELINE. hence, why I haven't done that.

That's correct - it's not supported. From the link above:
CodeBuild does not support build badges with the Amazon S3 source provider. Because AWS CodePipeline uses Amazon S3 for artifact transfers, build badges are not supported for build projects that are part of a pipeline created in CodePipeline. 

My source provider is bitbucket using codestarconnection. What else am I missing?

The fact that badges are not supported for CodePipeline.

Maybe then using cdk pipelines?

CDK Pipelines uses CodePipeline under the hood. You'll have to go with something custom - AWS does not support this natively.
